# Uninstall Xdebug 3 and install v2.9.8

Tags: php, xdebug

I've installed Xdebug in my system. Then in PhpStorm I've done all the configuration to debug the code using Xdebug.

But in Xdebug is not working properly with PhpStorm. So I would like to remove Xdebug from my local machine. But it's unable to uninstall it.

Using the following command I understood it was installed in my local machine:

`php -v` shows:

```
PHP 7.3.28-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun  4 2021 21:23:19) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.28, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.28-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

But while ran the uninstall command I am getting the following response in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove  php-xdebug
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'php-xdebug' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 58 not upgraded.
```

Previously I was using Xdebug v2.9.8, it was working fine and I was able to debug the code. So I would like to install the same version.

So looking forward for your support to uninstall version 3 and proper command to install version 2.9.8 in my PHP 7.3 version.

Comment: Xdebug 2 is no longer supported, and read the upgrade guide: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: Just reverse what you did to install it, simple as that. This is basically a system administration question, not one on programming. That said, Xdebug 3 has a different default port, which may not be obvious. Apart from that and a few changed settings, it works well, so I'd recommend fixing whatever issues you're getting instead of going back to an older version.

Comment: @senthil Read the migrate/upgrade guide (the link that Derick gave: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) and update your Xdebug config. PhpStorm supports Xdebug 3 just fine.